# Wacom intuos stopped working

Tags: wacom

I followed http://matthewwittering.com/blog/ubuntu-tips/how-to-install-a-wacom-intuos-ctl-480-tablet-on-ubuntu.html to set up my Intuos (CTH-680) to work with Ubuntu 13.10 desktop. It worked.

Then I noticed I need to repeat the last steps of that procedure after every reboot or 'suspend'. Otherwise it would not work - the modules would still be where they should be, but the tablet doesn't control the mouse any more, only gets its power from the computer, but has no effect. Repeating the last steps of the procedure fixed that.

Later on, I noticed that even after repeating the depmod modprobe and insmod commands as specified in the aforementioned procedure, it doesn't work, and I rather have to repeat most of the mentioned procedure once in a while for it to work. So I'm not sure if the need to repeat the procedure arises due to reboots, suspends, Ubuntu updates, or anything else.

It would be nice not having to repeat the procedure so any advice other than creating a script to run the procedure would be nice and informing.